# Oracle 10g, see exact query sent to database

Tags: sql, oracle10g, trace, enterprise

I have an application from a third party that writes to the Oracle database. One component of the application returns no data given particular parameters, while the other component of the application does return data with those same parameters. Nobody has the source code to this application, but it can be seen that the database has the proper information in it.

The misbehaving component gets `ORA-01403` returned from the oracle database server, which means no data found, but can be related to a syntax error, as seen by a packet sniffer I installed.

I want to see the differences in the queries that the different components of the application actually generate.

Would also like to run these queries on the command line or in some other database viewer to see what gets returned.

How can I monitor the database with a trace that actually shows the queries being made? I would also like to isolate these by IP address or source.

Using Oracle 10g Enterprise

Comment: IIRC, TOAD will do what you want

Comment: @KevinDTimm is there a trial or a free tool you know of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, TOAD will do what you want.

Additionally, there is a free trial - http://www.quest.com/toad-for-oracle/software-downloads.aspx

There are other interesting downloads (search oracle free toad) but I can't be sure of their legitimacy.

Comment: what about SQL Developer, that looks free if one already has an oracle account (I'm guessing that comes with the enterprise license)

Comment: I have used SQL Dev but don't know the answer - TOAD has so much functionality -- first product, first love :)

Comment: How is this done with TOAD? Doesn't seem that intuitive from the screenshots

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a copy anymore (hence the IIRC in my answer).  It's down the menu system, you can watch everything that's going on, I'm just not sure where anymore (haven't used it in quite a few years)

Answer (score 3):

I found this worked well for an AWS Oracle RDS instance. I ran the tcpdump from the linux instances connecting to the db...

```
tcpdump tcp port 1521 -s 0 -l -w -  | strings | perl -e '
while(<>) { chomp; next if /^[^ ]+[ ]*$/;
  if(/^(SELECT|UPDATE|DELETE|INSERT|SET|COMMIT|ROLLBACK|CREATE|DROP|ALTER)/i) {
    if (defined $q) { print "$q\n"; }
    $q=$_;
  } else {
    $_ =~ s/^[ \t]+//; $q.=" $_";
  }
}'
```

Hope that helps someone else.

Comment: Amazing thanks works great in RHEL to remote DB. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If your client connects directly to the database without any middle-tier layer, then you have two pretty much straightforward options.

First of all, figure out required session's ID using `v$session` view, and then either find your query in `v$sql`/`v$sql_text` by its hash value (you can check description of each in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/toc.htm)), or enable session-level sql trace [(1)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_monitor.htm#i1003679) [(2)](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL_Trace) and get your queries in a plain text trace file.

If you have a middle-tier then things get slightly more complicated but only in terms of figuring out the session you need to trace. You can always enable system-wide tracing though.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party but I ran into this problem and didn't want to installe something on the database server for a one off use, I wound up using wireshark; the queries were sent in plaintext and perfectly readable.